# why don't I get an error if I am assigning a variable's value, that has not been initialized to another variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

i) Here the numbers of squares are 6. And I am only providing 3 colors. when the for loop runs it assign background-color to the first 3 squares.
I want to know why it is not giving error when it is assigning colors[3] to squares[3]. when colors[3] have no value.

ii) And how is it different from other languages like java and c++?

```js
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var colors = ["rgb(146, 162, 109)", "rgb(204, 160, 23)", "rgb(9, 106, 144)"];
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // change colors of squares
    for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

#container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Color Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    
    <button id="reset">Change Colors</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does give an error - in fact, 3 errors.  If you look at your browser's console,you will see three entries saying: "Expected colour but found 'undefined'.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped."  Errors won't appear as popup messages (unless that's what you code for).

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask two questions. Also, Java and C++ are two completely different languages.

Comment: Also, please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. Is there no way to illustrate your question in less than 30 lines? I'm pretty sure I can do it in 11 characters.

Comment: Any object that does not exist in javascript is "undefined", so you could do colors[1000] and it would still be undefined.  If you want to check for that, you could put your code in a try/throw/catch/finally structure - [handling errors](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)  And then, in the try block, you check for `colors[i] === undefined` and throw a custom error- and handle that in the catch block.  Trying to set a color to `undefined` will not produce a code breaking error as it's just a value that a color style won't accept, so it is ignored - that's how css works.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know why it is not giving error when it is assigning colors[3] to squares[3]. when colors[3] have no value.

`colors[3]` *has* a value: [accessing a non-existing property evaluates to `undefined`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors).

```js
console.log([][3]);
```

Comment: How about adding an actual explanation or a reference or a link to the relevant spec to really explain the behavior (instead of only adding a _"it has a value"_)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case javascript is different from languages like Java and c++.

In java or c++, if you access any index greater then the length of array you will get index out of bound exception. But in javascript you will get `undefined`, and undefined is considered a data type in javascript.

For example:

```
const arr = [1];
console.log(arr[5]); //undefined
```

Same is the case with objects, if you try to access any property of object which does not exists it will give you undefined. but in java or c++ it will throw an error.

Here you are just assigning undefined to your backgroundColor property that is why it is not throwing any error.